# C++, having difficulty inserting into a list

Tags: c++

So I have made a SortedArray class that I have tested and it works fine, but when I try and insert into a list I get read access violations whenever I try and access the SortedArray.

```
list* aList = new list<SortedArray<T>>();

//creates an array of T* with length l and filled with NULL pointers
SortedArray<DT>* sa = new SortedArray<T>(l); 

cout << endl <<sa[0] <<endl; //returns nothing because NULL 

aList->push_front(*sa); //is the *sa the problem?

//should return NULL as well but throws read access violation
cout << ((*aList->begin())[0]);
```

I put the cout<< lines in so I could see what was happening at each step, but I still wasn't able to figure out the problem.

Comment: `aList->push_front(*sa); //is the *sa the problem?` the problem, I dunno, but it is a problem. Sets you up for a memory leak if you're not careful.

Comment: `list* aList = new list<SortedArray<T>>();` doesn't look right. I'd expect `list<SortedArray<T>>* aList = new list<SortedArray<T>>();`, but there's a lot of completely unnecessary pointer action here.  `list<SortedArray<T>> aList;` is probably all you need

Comment: Why are you pushing the element pointed to by the `sa`, i.e `*sa` to the list? should you not be pushing `sa` itself ?

Comment: Why so much `new`? There's almost never a good reason to use `new` in modern C++.

Comment: Is `operator<<` overloaded to take a `SortedArray<T>` type?

Comment: Do you need a list of sorted arrays?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> list* aList = new list<SortedArray<T>>();
> ```

This creates a new `list` object that holds actual `SortedArray<T>` objects and not pointers to objects.

> ```
> SortedArray<DT>* sa = new SortedArray<T>(l);
> ```

This creates a new `SortedArray` object that (presumably) holds actual `DT` objects and not pointers to `DT` objects.

> ```
> cout << endl <<sa[0] <<endl; //returns nothing because NULL
> ```

In this statement, `sa` is a pointer, so you are performing pointer arithmetic instead of invoking `SortedArray::operator[]` (assuming there is one).  Because `sa` is a pointer, `sa[0]` is the same as `*(sa+0)`, so you are passing a `SortedArray` object to `operator<<` (which will not compile unless you have overloaded `operator<<` to take a `SortedArray` as input).  If you want to instead pass the first element of the `SortedArray`, you need to dereference the pointer before you can invoke `SortedArray::operator[]`:

```
cout << endl << (*sa)[0] <<endl;
```

> ```
> aList->push_front(*sa); //is the *sa the problem?
> ```

This statement is fine, provided that `SortedArray` has implemented a proper copy constructor.  `push_front()` will make a copy of the `SortedArray` object that you pass in, so make sure that you are copying array elements correctly from one `SortedArray` to another.  Chances are that you are probably not, which could lead to the Access Violation that you are experiencing.

> ```
> //should return NULL as well but throws read access violation
> cout << ((*aList->begin())[0]);
> ```

This is another area where the C++ syntax is getting the better of you.  You apparently want to call the `list`'s `begin()` method to get an iterator to the first element, and then dereference that iterator to access the `SortedArray` object, and then call `operator[]` on that array.  To do that correctly (and to make the code more readable), you should rearrange your parenthesis:

```
cout << (*(aList->begin()))[0];
```